# How to use a lot of memory in node.js?

Tags: node.js, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am working on a system designed to keep processes behaving properly and I need to test its memory usage kill switch. I am yet to find a way to quickly and efficiently use a lot of system memory quickly with node.js. I have tried using arrays but it seems as if the garbage collector compresses them. Basically, I need to deliberately cause a fast memory leak.

EDIT: I need to reach around 4 gigabytes of used system memory by one process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If garbage collector is compressing your array, maybe you are pushing always the same value inside it.

you should try shomething like

```
const a = []
for (let i = 0; i < 9000000000; i++)
    a.push(i)
```

You also should run your process with a flag to increase memory limit. Note that with a limit of 9B, your array should be bigger than 4GB and your process will exit with non zero status code.

> node --max_old_space_size=4096 yourscript.js

Comment: This does the job perfectly, and with some improvements, I can adjust it to fill up just the right amount of memory.